# Checking Google Play Receipt is enough to secure my player prefs data in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, in-app-purchase

To be specific I am working now on storing the data of my game project, which depends on the IAP service from Google Play.

I am using playerprefs that Unity provides and I know that this is not secure. So, I had the idea to get the receipt of what this player purchased from the game: if the user has purchased an item he can use it, if not he can't.

So this way is secure enough for my game?

This game using Unity and it is a multiplayer online game, and I don't have the ability to user server side authentication, that is why I am thinking about this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yep

This is actually in the documentation for the IAP services and is considered the only way to validate in app purchases.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is incorrect.

> This is actually in the documentation for the IAP services and is
>   considered the only way to validate in app purchases.

The `IPurchaseReceipt` you get from Unity's receipt validator can be casted to a `GooglePlayReceipt`. Then, you can send `GooglePlayReceipt.purchaseToken`, `GooglePlayReceipt.productID`, and `GooglePlayReceipt.packageName` from that receipt to your own server, which can then use Google Play Developer API to validate the purchase.

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get

> So this way is secure enough for my game?

It really depends on the type of app, but between hosting costs and the amount of work involved, it may not be worth it to implement server-side receipt validation.